# How can one write a robust ListableQ function?

Tags: function-construction, attributes, expression-test

I would like to have a test that determines if a particular function is Listable.  In the case of Symbols this is merely a matter of checking `Attributes`.  `Function` definitions with the `Listable` attribute are a bit more involved but quite easy.

**However I specifically want to test for *inherent listability* in as many cases as possible.**

For example consider the function from **Case #4** in [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica):

```
(3 - #)/(7 * #) &
```

This function is *inherently listable*:

```
fn = (3 - #)/(7*#) &;
Map[fn, {1, 2, 3}]
fn @ {1, 2, 3}
```

> ```
> {2/7, 1/14, 0}
> {2/7, 1/14, 0}
> ```

- One must consider Functions with multiple arguments, both the `Slot` and named parameter type.
- Ideally the test would handle pattern-based (DownValues) functions to the extent that is possible.

Comment: What if your list is `{3, 4, {1,2}}`? Then, listable `f`, gives `{f[3], f[4], {f[1], f[2]}}`. So, while `(3 - #)/(7 #)&` is inherently listable, I don't think it is completely listable. So, `ListableQ` will have some limitations.

Comment: @rcollyer `/` is a listable binary operator so it works out fine since both arguments will have the same shape.

Comment: @rcollyer I don't see the problem with your example.  Perhaps you have another one?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard initially it was very clear to me when I wrote, not so much now, especially with ssch's comment. I need to see if I can recover what I intended, but my mental tape drive is faulty. :P

Comment: @rcollyer I know that feeling.  Too well.

Comment: Do you have a strict definition of what you call inherent listability, or you are looking for something that more or less works in the most common cases?

Comment: @Rojo I didn't (and don't) have a strict definition.  "... and moreover, that the question itself may be hard to answer in a complete way."  What are you thinking?  I should revisit this some time but as you may have noticed I'm taking a break from *Mathematica*.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed. Why is that?

Comment: @Rojo I was feeling burned out.  I decided to take a break before I started to dislike spending time here.  I still stop by at least daily to check for fires (flags).

Comment: How about this? :) Just check the FullForm function in this list `Select[Names["*"], MemberQ[Attributes[#], Listable] &]`

Comment: @NamNguyen That is what I meant by "In the case of Symbols this is merely a matter of checking Attributes."

Answer (score 6):

This is what I have so far.  It's far from complete, but still a good start I think.

```
listableQ[s_Symbol] /; MemberQ[Attributes @ s, Listable] := True
listableQ[s_Symbol] := MatchQ[DownValues[s], {__?test2}]

listableQ[Verbatim[Function][_, _, attr_]] /; ! FreeQ[{attr}, Listable] := True
listableQ[Verbatim[Function][vars_, body_, ___]] := test1[vars, body]
listableQ[body_ &] := 
  Cases[Unevaluated[body], _Slot, {0, -1}, Heads -> True] /. x_ :> test1[x, body]

SetAttributes[test1, HoldAll];
test1[vars_, body_] :=
  Cases[Unevaluated[body],
    h_[args___] /; ! FreeQ[Unevaluated[{args}], Alternatives @@@ HoldPattern[vars]] :> h,
    {0, -1}
  ] ~MatchQ~ {__?listableQ}

test2[lhs_ :> rhs_] :=
  Union @@ Cases[Unevaluated[lhs],
    Verbatim[Pattern][p_, _] :> Hold[p],
    {0, -1}, Heads -> True
  ] /. x_ :> test1[x, rhs]
```

Here is a very basic test; `qq` represents a generic function that isn't listable.

```
ff[a_, b__, c : _List] := a^2/Sign[b^2 + c] + qq[z]
f2[a_, b__, c : _List] := qq[a, b^2] + c

listableQ /@ {
  (3 - #)/(7*#) &,
  (3 - #)/(qq[7]*#) &,
  qq[(3 - #), (7*#)] &,
  Function[x, x + qq[5] + x/2],
  Function[x, qq[x + 5, x/2]],
  Function[, qq[(3 - #), (7*#)], Listable],
  ff,
  f2
 }
```

> {True, True, False, True, False, True, True, False}

Comment: I am aware that there are ways that this fails, and moreover, that the question itself may be hard to answer in a complete way.  For example, if `qq[7]` were to return `{1, 2}` this would break listability of second function.  Nevertheless I am interested in exploring and improving this kind of test.

Comment: Additionally I realize that my `ff` and `f2` functions are poorly conceived; they were hasty examples.  I'll revisit this tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

The naive one-argument test:

```
naiveListableQ[f_] := f[{1, 2}] === f /@ {1, 2}
```

Cons:

- Evaluates the function
- Can give incorrect result
- {1,2} has to be in domain of function
- ...

Results:

```
naiveListableQ /@ {
  (3 - #)/(7*#) &,
  (3 - #)/(qq[7]*#) &,
  qq[(3 - #), (7*#)] &,
  Function[x, x + qq[5] + x/2],
  Function[x, qq[x + 5, x/2]],
  Function[, qq[(3 - #), (7*#)], Listable],
 }
```

> {True, True, False, True, False, True}

Comment: I considered this approach and decided to go a different direction.  It may be the most rigorous approach for anonymous functions that don't contain pattern matching.  However, I don't like the fact that it does evaluate the function (multiple times) which works against the applications I have in mind.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard CW was intentional as it was bit too long for a comment. Except for the simplicity of it I don't like it either :)