# Two ways to map a function on a list: Which one is faster?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, attributes, function-comparison

There are two ways to make a function listable on the list: Use `Map` or use `SetAttributes`. My question is, which one is faster, more efficient? Does `SetAttributes` use `Map` or another way?

```
In[135]:= f/@{1,2,3}
Out[135]= {f[1],f[2],f[3]}

In[136]:= g[{1,2,3}]
Out[136]= g[{1,2,3}]

In[137]:= SetAttributes[g,Listable]
          g[{1,2,3}]
Out[138]= {g[1],g[2],g[3]}
```

=== EDIT ===

Thank for the comments of @Yves Klett and of @Leonid, I do a check:

There are so many functions that are listable in *Mathematica*; I wonder that help improving performance in *Mathematica*. There are total 379 `Listable` built-in functions.

```
Select[Names["*"],MemberQ[Attributes[#],Listable]&]//Length
379
```

I'm interested in numerical calculation, so I do the `Timing` check:

```
list=N[Range[10^7]];

Sin/@list;//AbsoluteTiming
{0.721041, Null}

Sin[list]; // AbsoluteTiming
{0.147008, Null}
```

We found that `Listable` is much faster than using `Map`.
So for numerical evaluation, should I `SetAttribute` my function as `Listable` instead of using `Map`?

Comment: May I suggest you to test both Timings[]?

Comment: For internal functions like `Sqrt` or `Sin` (...) with attribute `Listable` directly supplying lists as argument will be usually faster than using `Map` (at least for numeric input).

Comment: Usually `Listable` for top-level functions (meaning, set by the user) does not provide much of a speed advantage over `Map`, if at all. But it can make things worse, because `Map` auto-compiles, when it can - `Listable` will prevent that. I would say that the advantages of user-set `Listable` are mostly not in speed but elsewhere - e.g. sometimes it can lead to very concise code. As @YvesKlett noted, it is different for numeric functions, and other built-in `Listable` functions - there `Listable` basically means that you push more work to the kernel, and this will always be faster.

Comment: Just remember that `Listable`'s full behaviour cannot be replaced by `Map`

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, by the way, do you know if it is possible to emulate that behaviour of built-ins? I mean, making your function listable but being able to create overload to optimize, for example, for numeric lists.

Comment: @Rojo Fighting `Listable` is almost impossible, AFAIK. You can do e.g. this: ``ClearAll[f];SetAttributes[f, Listable];
f[x_] := x^2;f /; MemberQ[Stack[_], HoldForm[f[_?Developer`PackedArrayQ]]] := (#^2 &)``, but to my mind, this is hardly worth the effort in most cases. This will also make the function seriously slower on non-numeric lists, because it will have to inspect the `Stack` at every invocation. Much simpler is to emulate Listability with an explicit rule like ``f[x_List/;!Developer`PackedArrayQ[x]]:=Map[f,x];f[x_]:=x^2``.

Comment: @Rojo Also, Mr.Wizard was interested in "`ListableQ`" function, there should be some discussion of it here on SE.

Comment: @DaoTRINH I already addressed your question in your edit, in my comment, but I will repeat again: there are two types of listability - the one in built-in functions, which pushes threading into the kernel and is fast, and the top-level one (setting `Listable` for some functions by the user). You *can not* achieve built-in listability by simply setting a Listable attribute, so for most cases, it *will not* speed things up. The reason is that, while the end result is the same - automatic threading over lists, the underlying mechanisms to achieve it are different for built-ins vs user-defined.

Comment: Thank you Leonid Shifrin. It's clear now for me.

Comment: @DaoTRINH No problem, was glad to help.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

#### The role and meaning of `Listable`

The `Listable` attribute serves to impose automatic threading over lists for symbols for which it is set (or present from the start, for some built-in functions).

Conceptually, `Listable` attribute is more or less equivalent to

```
ClearAll[setListable];
setListable[f_]:=
   call:f[left___,l_List,right___]:=
      Module[{myHold},             
         SetAttributes[myHold,HoldAll];             
         With[
             {
                heldres=
                   Hold[Evaluate[Quiet[Check[myHold[left,l,right]//. 
                      m_myHold:>Thread[m],$Failed]]]]/. 
                          myHold->f
             },  
             If[heldres===Hold[$Failed],
                 Message[Thread::tdlenMessageName,call]
             ];
             ReleaseHold[heldres]/;heldres=!=Hold[$Failed]&&heldres=!=Hold[call]
         ]
      ];
```

so that e.g.

```
ClearAll[f];
setListable[f];
f[{1, 2, 3}, 1]
f[{{1, 2, 3}}, {{4, 5, 6}}, 1]
```

give

```
(* {f[1, 1], f[2, 1], f[3, 1]} *)

(* {{f[1, 4, 1], f[2, 5, 1], f[3, 6, 1]}}  *)
```

but when there are more than one lists passed, and of different lengths, it is then an error:

```
f[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[666]:= Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in f[{1,2,3},{4,5}] cannot be combined. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[666]:= Thread::tdlen: Objects of unequal length in f[{1,2,3},{4,5}] cannot be combined. >>
> ```

```
(* f[{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}] *)
```

what is important is that threading over lists happens before any user-defined `DownValues` fire for `f`, or `UpValues` fire for the arguments of `f`. So, this threading happens at a pretty early stage in the evaluation.

### Built-in `Listable` functions

There are two types of listability - the one in built-in functions, which pushes threading into the kernel and is fast, and the top-level one (setting Listable for some functions by the user).

You can not achieve built-in listability by simply setting a `Listable` attribute. The reason is that, while the end result is the same - automatic threading over lists, the underlying mechanisms to achieve it are different for built-ins vs user-defined. When a built-in `Listable` function (particularly numerical) is passed lists as arguments, it dispatches to the special branch which internally runs the loop, and returns a list of results. So, for a built-in function, `Listable` is rather a signal to pick the internal branch which deals with lists automatically.

#### `Listable` vs. `Map` or `Thread`

Imagine that you have a function `f`, for example

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_]:=Sow[x]
```

You may want to sow all elements of a nested list, in which case you can either 
write

```
f[x_List]:=Map[f,x]
```

or set the `Listable` attribute:

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f,Listable]
f[x_]:=Sow[x]
```

What is important to understand here:

- The two forms are more or less speed-equivalent for top-level functions (but see the next point)
- If you set the `Listable` attribute for a top-level function, then your definition based on `Map` has no chance to apply, even if present, because `Listable` - based threading happens much earlier in the evaluation sequence.
- Both methods can give inferior speed as compared to explicit mapping, since you can use pure functions or other compilable functions in explicit mapping, and `Map` auto-compiles.

#### Worst-case scenario: spoiling built-in Listability via intermediate top-level `Listable` function

The worst thing you can do in terms of speed is e.g. the following:

```
ClearAll[f] 
SetAttributes[f,Listable];
f[x_]:=x^2
```

Why? Because the `Power` function is internally `Listable`, so that you can simply define:

```
ClearAll[ff];
ff[x_]:=x^2
```

and apply this to a list without using explicit `Map`. But when you set `f` as `Listable`, you force the top-level (slow) threading before the more efficient internal threading has a chance to apply.

Here are some examples:

```
(res1 = ff[test]); // AbsoluteTiming
(res2 = Map[#^2 &, test]); // AbsoluteTiming
(res3 = f[test]); // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.016720, Null} *)

(* {0.056495, Null} *)

(* {0.815428, Null}  *)
```

You can see that the direct application is leveraging built-in `Listable` attribute of `Power` and is very fast. The `Map` is slower, but still quite fast since it auto-compiles. But the top-level `Listable` attribute makes it two orders of magnitude slower.

#### Summary

So, in summary, here are some recommendations related to performance-tuning and `Listable` attribute:

- When you can use built-in `Listable` functions, just use them by passing entire lists to them and forget about the explicit `Listable` attribute.
- Explicit mapping with `Map` can often be quite efficient too.
- *Do not* use `Listable` attribute for speed, use it only for convenience / more compact and elegant code. In fact, the rule of thumb is that for numerical large arrays, chances are that top-level `Listable` is a wrong tool, while for certain symbolic manipulations can be a good option
- This *does not* apply to the `Listable` attribute you can set in your compiled functions when using `Compile` - by all means do this when you can, because this one acts similarly to the built-in `Listable` attribute.

Comment: Is this a bug or a feature? I've just run into this trap and accidentally slowed down listable operations by explicitly setting symbol attributes to Listable. If setting the attribute explicitly to a symbol/operation that has it built-in is not innocuous, that seems to be a design flaw to me. I'm not saying it's a bug (implementation-wise), but am I allowed to consider this a conceptual flaw? Why is setting the Listable attribute here not effect-free?

Comment: @AndreasLauschke IMO, this is just one of the consequence of several performance scales present in the language. All functions which work on packed arrays have efficient type-specialized branches for them, and for those functions (where it makes sense), `Listable` on the top level is just a confirmation that they indeed are `Listable`, but the way they achieve `Listable` behavior has nothing to do with the top-level attribute. OTOH, generically, you need to use `Listable` on general symbols, to make them behave as such. So, given the performance model of M, there is not much one can do.

Comment: @AndreasLauschke However, one can still do a few things. One can for example use the `listableQ` function from [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31499), and then write something like `ClearAll[setListable]; setListable[s_Symbol /; !listableQ[s]]:=SetAttributes[s, Listable]; setListable[s_Symbol]:=Null;` and then use `setListable` instead. To the extent that `listableQ` works, this would prevent you from spoiling the listability of already internally-listable symbols, and, more importantly, their combinations.

Comment: @AndreasLauschke Another possible improvement in this context would be to define and use your own version of `Map`, so that it actually does not use `Map` on internally `Listable` symbols: `ClearAll[lMap]; lMap[f_?listableQ, arg_List]:=f[arg]; lMap[args__]:=Map[args];`. Of course, this would become useful only if the overhead of `listableQ` is not greater than the overhead of explicit `Map`. OTOH, for a function you use many times, you can memoize the result of  `listableQ`.

Comment: @AndreasLauschke To answer your direct question, I guess that there isn't a fully robust way of testing for listability in general (given that the language is untyped and combinations of listable functions are also often listable), which would be at the same time fast enough in all cases. So, if you have `f[x_]:=some-code-using-x`, then the r.h.s. may in fact be able to thread over lists (so that `Listable` is not needed can can only harm performance), or it may not, and there is no general way to find that out. So, this is left to the user, in the same spirit as packed arrays / unpacking.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I like your listableQ. I still think that on functions which work on packed arrays using the top-level Listable attribute should just discard that effect-free instead of causing carnage (breaking listability). You write "confirmation that they are indeed Listable), but using it breaks the listability, which doesn't seem all that confirmatory to me at all.

Comment: @AndreasLauschke Well, the credit for `listableQ` goes to Mr.Wizard. As to top-level `Listable` attribute, it doesn't really *break* `Listability` semantically, it just replaces the low-level one with the much slower top-level one (so, it degrades performance). The problem is that when you have a function like `f[x_, a_,b_]:=x^a + x^b`, then while the r.h.s will automatically thread over `x` when `x` is a list (by virtue of `Plus` and `Power` being both low-level `Listable`), it is hard to confirm that robustly and efficiently in general. That's what `listableQ` helps with, to some extent.

Comment: Yes, we have to distinguish two levels of listability, a top-level version and a low-level version. And turning on the top-level version degrades the performance of the low-level version. I can't say I like the naming here.

Comment: @AndreasLauschke Well, semantically they do the same thing. The only difference is how they achieve it. I also dislike the situation, but having different names for them would explicitly bring performance into the language semantics, and that is something one wants to avoid as much as possible. The only real solution here is to move both performance scales towards each other, by e.g. developing a more general `Compile` (which is being worked on), that would compile top-level code, perhaps JIT and type-specialize, and would in many cases remove the effect of the top-level `Listable`.

Comment: I wonder if the Mathematica Kernel team, improve the code by using your listableQ, to get rid of these limits.

Comment: @NamNguyen Hard to tell whether that's going to happen anytime soon. As to `listableQ`, it actually was written by [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard), not me.