# Compile a listable function to be applied over list of lists

Tags: list-manipulation, compile

Consider a simple function

```
g[x_,y_,z_] := x + y + z;
```

(indeed, any multivariate function `g` will illustrate the same thing). And suppose we're given a list of list of the form,

```
list = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6} }
```

Without using `Compile`, if I want a result of the form `{ g[1,2,3], g[4,5,6] }`, I can use `Apply` to get,

```
resultlist = g @@@ list
```

**Question**: Suppose that I want to write a compiled, listable, version of `g`, such that,

```
g[list] = { g[1,2,3], g[4,5,6] }
```

How would we achieve the same result? I'd attempted to write a `Listable` of the form,

```
compileG = Compile[ {x,y,z}, 
                     x + y + z, 
                     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
                   ]
```

then it'll give me the error `CompiledFunction::cfct: Number of arguments 1 does not match the length 3 of the argument template.`  Of course, in this circumstance, I know that `compileG @@@ list` will still work.

However, in the actual application I have in mind, the `g` function will be involved and `list` is quite large, and hence, I want to take advantage of these options `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True` (which, at least according to here http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=3635, gives a very significant speed boost.)

Comment: You are not specific the argument list correctly (in the `Compile` function). Open up the docs and see the right way to do it or read the WalkingRandomly article thoroughly.

Comment: Can you please be more specific as to where I didn't setup my `Compile` function correctly? I'd read through the documentations (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuntimeAttributes.html) and the WalkingRandomly article. The toy function `compileG` will indeed compute

Comment: `compileG = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, Total[x], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]` then `compileG[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]` prints `{6., 15.}`

Comment: @Sektor Thanks! This is helpful.

Comment: You are welcome !

Comment: I'm voting to reopen, since the behavior of the comment-answer by Sektor is very much not obvious. Consider `g[x_List] := Total[x];SetAttributes[g,Listable]` instead. We would get `{{g[1],g[2],g[3]},{g[4],g[5],g[6]}}`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP From the docs for `RuntimeAttributes`: "If a compiled function with Listable attribute receives any arguments with higher rank than specified, the function will thread over these arguments."  See [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1816) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35319) for more discussion.

Comment: The two linked discussions are very lengthy and do briefly mention this behavior of compiled functions, but don't (I only had time to skim through) go into great depth. I think, this is worth a question of its own, unless this is already covered here.

Comment: BTW, alternate solution is `compileG = 
 Compile[{x, y, z}, x + y + z, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]; compileG[{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}]`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I just thought you (and others) might be interested.  Somewhere there is a comment by Leonid about the difference in how listability is implemented for symbols and for compiled functions. It's interesting, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I *am* interested, so much, that I'll create this question as soon as I can.

Answer (score 4):

[Sector](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5470/sektor) has given a solution for the specific example in the comment above:

```
compileG = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}}, Total[x], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}] 
compileG[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}]
```

However, whether this solution is extensible or not really depends on your actual code, you'd better add more details to your question if it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

> However, in the actual application I have in mind, the g function will be involved and list is quite large, and hence, I want to take advantage of these options RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True (which, at least according to here http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=3635, gives a very significant speed boost.)

The `Listable` attribute in the link works slightly differently.

```
g[x_,y_,z_] := x + y + z; (* Plus is Listable by default *)

compileG = Compile[{x,y,z}, x + y + z, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]

list = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
```

Neither of this works:

```
g[list]
compileG[list]
```

Having listability means being able to thread over lists.

```
Thread[{a, b}~g~{c, d}]
(* {g[a, c], g[b, d]} *)
```

Consequentially, `Listable` enables this to work:

```
compileG[xList, yList, zList]
```

For example:

```
{xList, yList, zList} = RandomReal[10., {3, 10}]
(* {
 {9.89594, 4.63021, 2.29814, 8.72035, 5.96282, 2.72297, 7.83348, 1.47251, 8.12116, 9.33473},
 {1.67636, 6.0282,  5.47119, 9.67162, 5.29997, 2.25684, 4.47208, 8.55757, 8.19018, 8.35372},
 {1.10912, 0.87434, 4.36243, 9.76855, 9.60058, 8.8579, 0.861787, 1.60515, 0.0182481, 0.795345}
} *)
compileG[xList, yList, zList]
(* {12.6814, 11.5328, 12.1318, 28.1605, 20.8634, 13.8377, 13.1673, 11.6352, 16.3296, 18.4838} *)
```

Comment: `Listable` also means `f@{a,b,c}` becomes `f /@ {a,b,c}`, i.e. `{f@a, f@b, f@c}`, see the other answers.