# Making pure functions listable

Tags: functions, pure-function

I have a very large number of functions defined in the following manner:

```
f[1] = Function[{x}, x^2];

f[2] = Function[{x}, x^3];
```

I would like to make all of these `Listable`. Is there any simple way of doing this? I have tried:

```
Attributes[f[2]] = {Listable};
```

and

```
SetAttributes[f[2],Listable];
```

both of which failed miserably!

Thanks!

Comment: `AppendTo[f[1], Listable]`?

Comment: Your functions (at least those you have as your examples) are already `Listable`, because `Power` operation maintains listability. Moreover, if you give them explicit `Listable` attribute, you will only make matters worse. Read [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35150/two-ways-of-map-a-function-on-the-list-which-one-is-faster).

Comment: My actual functions are way more complicated, this was just an example to see if this is possible.

Comment: Try this f[1] = Function[{x}, x^2]; f[2] = Function[{x}, x^3]; SetAttributes[f, Listable]; f[{1, 2}] but I doubt this is what you really want to do.

Comment: What @CarlWoll suggested may be a bit hard to understand, but he meant this: `f[1] = Function[{x}, x^2, Listable]`. Pure functions can have a subset of symbol attributes (including `Listable`), and then you specify them as a third optional argument to `Function`. Still, read the link I provided, to not run into nasty performance surprises. Because adding `Listable` attribute won't make the performance better, but can easily make it worse, so adding it for performance reasons doesn't make much sense, and can be counterproductive.

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thanks Carl Woll and Leonid Shifrin!