# Using the list as the argument of the pure function

Tags: functions, pure-function

I know some function is listable, such that

```
Sin@{1,2,3,4,5}
```

gives

```
{Sin[1], Sin[2], Sin[3], Sin[4], Sin[5]}
```

By reading some fundamental tutorials, I know the `Listable` is an efficient way to speed up the calculation so I want all my functions are `Listable` when applied to the list. Now I want to define this function: $f(x,y,z)=x+y^z$ and use it to calculate a list,for example $1+2^3$ and $4+5^6$.

```
f = #[[1]] + #[[2]]^#[[3]] &
SetAttributes[f, Listable]
f@{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}
```

I don't get the result. How can I write a pure function listable using the list as the argument?

Comment: If `f` were listable, then the output would be the result of `{{f[1], f[2], f[3]}, {f[4], f[5], f[6]}}`, which would result in errors, since the code for `f` calls on `Part`.

Comment: Is there any options that can control the `Listable` only applied for the first level?

Comment: Without `Listable`, if you define `f = #1 + #2^#3 &` then you can use `f @@@ {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}` to get your result... Not very helpful for understanding `Listable` better, though.

Comment: No, I think for controlling the level of listability, you have to use `Map` or `Apply`.  Note `Compile` can use listability in the way you desire.  But you're limited to what can be compiled.

Comment: Have a look at [this discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35150/two-ways-to-map-a-function-on-a-list-which-one-is-faster). In particular, using top-level `Listable` for speed may lead to the opposite effect, from what you are after.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think making functions [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable) is a good way to speed up computations, and in fact it can cause a slow down as discussed in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35319/45431) by @LeonidShifrin to the question [Two ways to map a function on a list: Which one is faster?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35150/45431). Let's take your example. Here is how you can make `f` [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable):

```
SetAttributes[f, Listable];
f[x_, y_, z_] := x + y^z
```

For your example input:

```
f[{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}]
```

> {9, 15629}

This example is simple enough that a [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace) might be helpful in understanding the process:

```
Trace[f[{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}]]
```

> {f[{1,4},{2,5},{3,6}],{f[1,2,3],f[4,5,6]},{f[1,2,3],1+2^3,{2^3,8},1+8,9},{f[4,5,6],4+5^6,{5^6,15625},4+15625,15629},{9,15629}}

The [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable) attribute causes `f[{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}]` to evaluate to `{f[1, 2, 3], f[4, 5, 6]}`. But, this evaluation is done in top-level code, so it is slow. Also, none of the arithmetic operations are vectorized (I will explain this later). Now, let's compare this with the same function with [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable) set to false:

```
ClearAttributes[g, Listable]
g[x_, y_, z_] := x + y^z
```

Here is a timing comparison between `f` and `g`:

```
{arg1, arg2, arg3} = RandomReal[10, {3, 10^6}];

r1 = f[arg1, arg2, arg3]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = g[arg1, arg2, arg3]; //AbsoluteTiming

r1 === r2
```

> {1.24893, Null}
>
> {0.00895, Null}
>
> True

We see that `g` is more than 2 orders of magnitude faster. This is because `g` only has one top level evaluation before doing the vectorized [`Plus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus) and [`Power`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power) evaluations (by vectorized I mean their listability is built-in to the kernel when dealing with packed arrays). Again, a [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace) might be helpful here:

```
Trace @ g[
    Developer`ToPackedArray@{1, 4},
    Developer`ToPackedArray@{2, 5},
    Developer`ToPackedArray@{3, 6}
]
```

> {{Developer`ToPackedArray[{1,4}],{1,4}},{Developer`ToPackedArray[{2,5}],{2,5}},{Developer`ToPackedArray[{3,6}],{3,6}},g[{1,4},{2,5},{3,6}],{1,4}+{2,5}^{3,6},{{2,5}^{3,6},{8,15625}},{1,4}+{8,15625},{9,15629}}

The arguments to `g` need to be packed in order for the [`Plus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus)/[`Power`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power) evaluations to be vectorized (fast). Notice how `{2, 5}^{3,6}` evaluates directly to `{8, 15625}`. That is, there is no intermediate step of `{2, 5}^{3, 6}` evaluating to `{2^3, 5^6}` and then evaluating `2^3. and`5^6`. This is why vectorized arithmetic is so much faster than non-vectorized arithmetic. If we didn't use packed arrays:

```
Trace @ g[
    {1, 4},
    {2, 5},
    {3, 6}
]
```

> {g[{1,4},{2,5},{3,6}],{1,4}+{2,5}^{3,6},{{2,5}^{3,6},{2^3,5^6},{2^3,8},{5^6,15625},{8,15625}},{1,4}+{8,15625},{1+8,4+15625},{1+8,9},{4+15625,15629},{9,15629}}

Notice how this time there are many extra arithmetic operations when compared to the vectorized (packed) version above. The moral of the story is that giving a function the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable) attribute can be useful for simplifying code, but it is rarely beneficial for improving speed.