# Unexpected output of a Listable function. Arguments not threaded correctly

Tags: function-construction, evaluation

I saw [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/161212/72284) asking about the Listable. The accepted answer did a good explanation on the poor performance of user defined function with Listable. However the answer didn't clarify why the `f` function in following code doesn't show Listable feature.

```
f = #[[1]] + #[[2]]^#[[3]] &;
SetAttributes[f, Listable];
f@{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}
```

output:
[image]
I Know why the code above cannot achieve its goal, and I know how to fix it.
I just don't think the above wrong code should produce the above specific output.
According to my understanding of how Listable thread function arguments, it should produce the following output:

```
{{f[1], f[2], f[3]}, {f[4], f[5], f[6]}}
```

Because the list `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}` as argument should be threaded to the innermost level, which in the end is `{{f[1], f[2], f[3]}, {f[4], f[5], f[6]}}` and stop with some error message since f has Part on the argument.

However, in the reality, the real output shows that actually no Listable is in effect. The List `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}` is passed to `f` as one whole arguments, which can also be proved  by running a Trace on it.

Someone please help me?

Comment: Here are a few hints: `SetAttributes[]` will only work if you had defined `f` as `f[v_] := v[[1]] + v[[2]]^v[[3]]`. Otherwise, an anonymous function with attributes has to be declared this way: `f = Function[Null, #[[1]] + #[[2]]^#[[3]], {Listable}]`. Now, try your examples again with this in mind.

Comment: Wolfram surprised me again! I've recently read tons of articles on Documentation website , nowhere had I ever seen it says that `SetAttributes` work differently for `f=Function[x, ...]` and `f[x_]`!