# Is it possible to make listable Experimental`NumericalFunction?

Tags: function-construction, numerics, programming, undocumented, attributes

I have been playing a bit with the undocumented function

```
Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction
```

and I wanted to know if somebody found a way to make generated numerical functions listable.

Here is an example: I define two functions, `f` and `fC`

```
In[1]:=f = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{x}, x^2, {}, {_Real},WorkingPrecision -> 30];

In[2]:=fC = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, x^2, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
```

The first function is not listable, while the second is:

```
In[3]:=f@Table[i, {i, 1, 10}]
Out[3]:=Experimental`NumericalFunction[{x}, x^2,"-NumericalFunctionData-"][{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}]

In[4]:=fC@Table[i, {i, 1, 10}]
Out[4]:={1., 4., 9., 16., 25., 36., 49., 64., 81., 100.}
```

Is there a way to make `f` also listable?

Comment: What even is ``Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction``?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction is the closest one can get to compiling a function with arbitrary precision. As far as I can tell, Compile for now only takes Real64 arguments... Something like Real128 is still not available (not sure it will ever be).

Comment: Strongly related: "[How to work with Experimental`NumericalFunction?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43513/280)."

Comment: One could always wrap it with a `Listable` function: `fL = Function[x, f[x], Listable]`

Answer (score 8):

I do not know a way to make `` Experimental`NumericalFunction `` listable itself, but depending of your goals you can achieve the same behavior in several ways.

The simplest way is to create a proxy `Symbol` with `Listable` attribute:

```
ClearAll[f, fL]
SetAttributes[fL, Listable]
fL[x_] := f[x]
f = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{x}, x^2, {}, {_}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
fL@Table[i, {i, 1, 10}]
```

> ```
> {1.`30., 4.`30., 9.`30., 16.`30., 25.`30., 36.`30., 49.`30., 64.`30., 81.`30., 100.`30.}
> ```

It is also possible to assign the `Listable` attribute directly to `f`:

```
ClearAll[f]
SetAttributes[f, Listable]
f[x_] = Block[{x},
  Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{x}, x^2, {}, {_Real}, WorkingPrecision -> 30][x]]
f@Table[i, {i, 1, 10}]
```

> ```
> {1.`30., 4.`30., 9.`30., 16.`30., 25.`30., 36.`30., 49.`30., 64.`30., 81.`30., 100.`30.}
> ```

Instead of the attribute one can program listability via `Map` what [can be even faster](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35319/280):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[l_List] := f /@ l;
f[x_] = Block[{x},
   Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{x}, x^2, {}, {_Real}, WorkingPrecision -> 30][x]];
f@Table[i, {i, 1, 10}]
```

> ```
> {1.`30., 4.`30., 9.`30., 16.`30., 25.`30., 36.`30., 49.`30., 64.`30., 81.`30., 100.`30.}
> ```

Another way is to create a listable pure function:

```
ClearAll[f]
f = With[{f = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{x}, x^2, {}, {_Real}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]},
         Function[x, f[x], Listable]];
f@Table[i, {i, 1, 10}]
```

> ```
> {1.`30., 4.`30., 9.`30., 16.`30., 25.`30., 36.`30., 49.`30., 64.`30., 81.`30., 100.`30.}
> ```

Or you can `Map` `f` at level `-1` (assuming that your input matrix contains only numbers and not expressions):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{x}, x^2, {}, {_Real}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
table = Table[i, {i, 1, 10}];
Map[f, table, {-1}]
```

> ```
> {1.`30., 4.`30., 9.`30., 16.`30., 25.`30., 36.`30., 49.`30., 64.`30., 81.`30., 100.`30.}
> ```

Also it is possible to create a numerical function accepting a list of fixed length (but probably it isn't sufficient for you):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[{{x, {10}}}, x^2, {10}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
f@Table[i, {i, 1, 10}]
```

> ```
> {1.`30., 4.`30., 9.`30., 16.`30., 25.`30., 36.`30., 49.`30., 64.`30., 81.`30., 100.`30.}
> ```

Comment: Dear Alexey, in the end the best option for me was to use
``` Map[f,table,{-1}]```
Thanks for all your help!