# How to make a function with two patterns listable?

Tags: operators, attributes

Suppose that I have a function that has two patterns:

```
disksConstantRadius[radius_][points_] := Disk[#, radius] & /@ points
```

(noting that this would be better---but less readable---as)

```
disksConstantRadii[radius_?NumericQ][points_ /; ArrayQ[points, 2,NumericQ]] := 
 Disk[#, radius] & /@ points
```

The above works just fine.

The objective is to make an operator form of Disk that operates on a list of points, but the question is more general.

*Is there a name for this construction f[**][**]??*

This is just idle curiosity (I clearly have a work-around), but would it be possible to make the function be  Listable in its second argument?

I'm not surprised that this

```
Clear[disksConstantRadius];
Attributes[disksConstantRadius] = {Listable}
disksConstantRadius[radius_?NumericQ][{x_, y_}] := 
 Disk[{x, y}, radius]
```

doesn't work.

And also not surprised that this:

```
Clear[disksConstantRadius];
Attributes[disksConstantRadius[_]] = {Listable}
disksConstantRadius[radius_?NumericQ][{x_, y_}] := 
 Disk[{x, y}, radius]
```

doesn't work either.

How could one construct an operator form `disksConstantRadius[radius]`?

There is a nice discussion about Listable here: [The role and meaning of Listable, Leonid Shifrin, 2013](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35150/two-ways-to-map-a-function-on-a-list-which-one-is-faster/35319#35319)

Comment: "Listable" works for any nesting depth. That means your function would act on every coordinate separately. Therefore, you do not want a function, that should take a vector (e.g. a point) as input, to be listable. The way to go is using "Map"

Comment: The Map method is embodied in the first two examples which works just fine. Another solution is `diskConstantRadii[r_] :=diskConstantRadii[r]= Compile[{{p,_Real,1}}, Evaluate[Disk[{Indexed[p,1].Indexed[p,1]},r],Attributes->Listable]`.  I’m just curious how one might do the f[][] version programmaticaly. My goal is to learn a new tick.

Comment: Edit, above comment should be {Indexed[p,1],Indexed[p,2]}

Comment: You can't make `f` listable if the basic call has the form `f[{x_, y_}]`. If `f` is listable, then `f[{x, y}]` becomes `{f[x], f[y]}` before any definitions for `f` are applied. It doesn't matter whether `f` is a symbol or a head like `disksConstantRadius[r]`. It can't be done via `Listable`. The restriction on subvalues is a red herring, and you have to use `Map` or `Thread`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an alternative to `Listable`. It's somewhat the opposite to `Listable`, but it's also the opposite to unlistable. More like relistable: If given a simple list, change it to a list of lists.

```
ClearAll[disksConstantRadius];
disksConstantRadius[radius_?NumericQ][p_?VectorQ] /;
    Length@p == 2 := 
  disksConstantRadius[radius][{p}];
disksConstantRadius[radius_?NumericQ][pts_?MatrixQ] /; 
    Last@Dimensions@pts == 2 :=
  Thread[Disk[pts, radius]];
```

The conditions `Length@p == 2` and `Last@Dimensions@pts == 2` are somewhat optional depending on where you want the function call to fail, if it is called with data that are not coordinates of points in the plane.

Example:

```
disksConstantRadius[1][RandomReal[1, {3, 2}]]
(*
  {Disk[{0.631657, 0.646406}, 1],
   Disk[{0.223139, 0.962916}, 1], 
   Disk[{0.260601, 0.75212}, 1]}
*)
```

One thing that differs with the OP's description of the function is that `disksConstantRadius` always gives a list of disks, which might be an advantage in dealing with its output.

```
disksConstantRadius[1][{3, 7}]
(*
  {Disk[{3, 7}, 1]}
*)
```

One might want to add a rule for an empty list, to mimic the standard behavior of `Listable` functions:

```
disksConstantRadius[radius_?NumericQ][{}] := {};
```

Comment: Clever! Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

A few comments:

- Values of the form `f[][]` are called [`SubValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubValues.html).
- For example, if one defines `f[x_][y_]:=x+y`, then this definition is to be found not in `DownValues[f]` but in `SubValues[f]`.
- See also [How do you set attributes on SubValues?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/544) and [Currying with Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686494).
- Instead of the [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) attribute, one can use `f[x_][y_List]:=Map[f[x],y]`. Or, perhaps more appropriate for OP, `f[x_][y:{_List...}]:=Map[f[x],y]`.

Comment: I'd probably use `f[x_][y_?MatrixQ]...` if `y` is likely to be a medium to large packed array or `f` will be called a lot.