# Make input function listable

Tags: attributes

I have a function taking a function as input as well as other values, e.g.

```
f2[f_, a_, b_, c_, d_] = f[{a, b}, c, d];
```

Of course, the behavior differs for f1 being `Listable` or not. So if I define

```
f1[x_, y_, z_] = If[x > 0, x*y + z, -x + y + z]
```

it will yield

```
In= Attributes[f1] = {};f2[f1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Out= If[{1, 2} > 0, {1, 2} 3 + 4, -{1, 2} + 3 + 4]
```

in contrast to

```
In= SetAttributes[f1, Listable]; f2[f1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Out= {7, 10}
```

.

Now my question is: can I implement that `f2` will always treat the given input function as `Listable`? So that I don't have to explicitely give the Attribute to the input function beforehand and still get the listable-ish output (in this case `{7,10}`.

I was trying

```
f3[f_, a_, b_, c_, d_] = Assuming[Element[Listable, Attributes[f]], f[{a, b}, c, d]];
```

but this behaves exactly like `f2`.

(Of course, in this simple case, I could map over the list `{a,b}` but let's assume this is not possible or not convenient.)

Comment: Why not use `Thread`? `Listable` is just an automatic `Thread`. `f3[f_, a_, b_, c_, d_] = Thread[f[{a, b}, c, d]];`

Comment: Right, this works, but I didn't come up with it because `Thread` didn't work in a similar though slightly different context

Comment: Can you tell me in what cases `Thread` does not work?

Comment: What do we know about `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` arguments? Can they be lists themselves? Do you want `f` function to thread them simultaneously with list you create in `f2` body? Explicit mapping is safest in this respect, since it won't accidentally thread where you don't want it.

Comment: If performance is relevant then [How can one write a robust ListableQ function?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31498/14303) might be related.

Comment: @happyfish I had too many mapping constructs on one single pure function (defined with `#1, #2, etc`) and it simply got too complicated to do the mapping in the right order.

Comment: @jkuczm as mentioned below, a/b are strings, the other arguments are just real numbers, so no lists or so. `{a,b}` is actuall explicitely given in the definition of `f2`as `{"T","S"}`.

Comment: @jkuczm Thanks for the link, but i don't get the connection. For my functions I know that in 99% of the cases they are not directly listable, but in 100% of the cases it works when giving them the attribute.

Comment: It seems `ListableQ` is not useful in your use case. It would be if you'd have large numeric lists over which you'd like listable function to map, then adding top level `Listable` attribute could spoil performance of built-in listable functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to modify `f1` globally, then you can do it locally:

```
ClearAll[f1, f2listable];
f1[x_, y_, z_] := If[x > 0, x*y + z, -x + y + z]
f2listable[f_, a_, b_, c_, d_] := 
 Module[{g}, g[x_, y_, z_] := f[x, y, z]; SetAttributes[g, Listable]; g[{a, b}, c, d]]

f2listable[f1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

> `{7, 10}`

Comment: Ah right, of course Module works nicely. However, other solutions would be interesting, too (if they exist)

Comment: @riddleculous You mentioned in the OP you are not willing to use any of the functions that apply functions over lists. What is the reason for this?

Comment: For modifying attributes/general function behavior, I use ``Internal`InheritedBlock`` which acts like `Block` except the original behavior is still present, i.e. you can modify the existing behavior, temporarily. So, I would use ``f2listable[...] := Internal`InheritedBlock[{f1}, SetAttributes[f1, Listable]; f1[...]]``.

Comment: @rcollyer that is a very nice solution!

Comment: @Stitch because in my case, it's more complicated and I use `Apply` for other arguments of `f1` which makes the use of Map impossible or at least very confusing here

Comment: @rcollyer nice, i like the brevity! Though I can't assess whether to prefer the `Module`or the `Internal`InheritedBlock` approach

Comment: @riddleculous There could be a potential for other functions that combine functionality, but without knowing other details, it seems like this or the rcollyer solution might be a way to go.

Comment: @Stitch both approaches work and execute in almost the same time in my case, so I'm happy with both of them

Comment: @riddleculous brevity without obscurity is a nice attribute for code. An advantage of `Module` is it let's you create a unique closure around a symbol. For instance, I've in code injection where I need to wrap my code around multiple functions, but need a unique control variable for each. :)

Comment: @riddleculous What do we know about functions that will be passed as first argument of `f2`? If it can be an anonymous function, or symbol that modifies itself in any way that should be persistent, or recurrent function for which listability can break any of internal calls, then `InheritedBlock` is ruled out. Stitch's version is safer in this respect since it uses lexical scoping, personally id use `Function[, f@##, Listable][{a, b}, c, d]` or `With[{fListable = Function[, f@##, Listable]}, fListable[{a, b}, c, d]]` it it needs to be called more than once.

Comment: @riddleculous Can this function have any relevant `Hold...` attributes, if so then lexical scoping based solution would require slightly  more work, than `InheritedBlock`, to take this into account.

Comment: @jkuczm for practical reasons, the function `f1` is defined directly when calling `f2[f1,a,b,c,d]` and looks like `f1=f3[#1,#2,#3,d]&`, i.e. I would like to call `f2[f3[#1,#2,#3,d]&,a,b,c,d]`. Here, `f3` is a list of simple matrices and it depends on the first argument (a string) how it will look like, i.e. there are two definitions `f3]"a",x_,y_]:=…` and `f3]"b",x_,y_]:=…` (to make it more complicated, f3 doesn't distinguish itself between "a" and "b" but the functions called by f3 do.)

Comment: @riddleculous So Stitch's answer seems to be the way to go. I'd prefer pure `Function` and `With` if necessary, as in my previous comment, but difference between those approaches is more stylistic than functional.